# the_category function is not working properly; the categories are not showing where they are supposed to be

Tags: php, wordpress, function, categories

I have this Related Posts section in my portfolio page, and I'm trying to generate the categories for each post with "the_category" function. In this case, the post on the left has categories "Photo, Test" and the rest has the category "Blog".

The function seems to be working properly, but as you can see in the attached image, the categories are showing above the title.

I want the categories to be generated within the "listing_meta" block. (Next to the comments)

```
    <div class="blog_content">          
        <div class="listing_meta">
           <span>'. esc_html(get_the_time(get_option('date_format'))) .'</span>     
           <span class="blog_post_author">'. __('by', 'gt3_builder') .' <a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID')).'" class="text-capitalize">'.get_the_author_meta('display_name').'</a></span>
           <span class="comments"><a href="' . get_comments_link() . '">'. get_comments_number(get_the_ID()) .'</a></span>
           <span>'. the_category(', ') .'</span>
        </div>
        <div class="blog_post_title"><h2><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2><div class="blog_post_format_label"></div></div>
    </div>
```

[image: S]

Is there any solution for this?

Thank you.

-------------------------Edited-------------------------------

I tried the function "get_the_category", but now it returns all the categories as ARRAY as shown in the image.

```
    <div class="blog_content">          
        <div class="listing_meta">
           <span>'. esc_html(get_the_time(get_option('date_format'))) .'</span>     
           <span class="blog_post_author">'. __('by', 'gt3_builder') .' <a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID')).'" class="text-capitalize">'.get_the_author_meta('display_name').'</a></span>
           <span class="comments"><a href="' . get_comments_link() . '">'. get_comments_number(get_the_ID()) .'</a></span>
           <span>'. get_the_category() .'</span>
        </div>
        <div class="blog_post_title"><h2><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2><div class="blog_post_format_label"></div></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get_the_category()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

That is the function you want.  If you use

```
the_category()
```

It will immediately echo that, which will then echo out before the rest of your content.

---------------EDIT--------------
If more than one category is returned, you can convert the array to a comma delimited list of categories with foreach:

```
//get all the categories
$categories = get_the_category();

//begin to assemble our string/html we want return/output
$returnedString = '<div class="blog_content">          
    <div class="listing_meta">
    <span>'. esc_html(get_the_time(get_option('date_format'))) .'</span>     
    <span class="blog_post_author">'. __('by', 'gt3_builder') .' <a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID')).'" class="text-capitalize">'.get_the_author_meta('display_name').'</a></span>
    <span class="comments"><a href="' . get_comments_link() . '">'. get_comments_number(get_the_ID()) .'</a></span>
    <span>';
//loop over the array of category objects
foreach($categories as $category){
    //append each category name to the returned string
    $returnedString .= $category->name . ',';
}
//add the remaining HTML
$returnedString .= '</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_post_title"><h2><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2><div class="blog_post_format_label"></div></div>
    </div>';
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, and they're inside the block perfectly. However, I have another issue. Now, it returns all the categories as ARRAY as shown in the second image..(I've updated the post) I don't know much about PHP, and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You're not including all the code that is happening around the HTML, because it looks like that HTML is being returned from a function or set into a variable, so I'll update my answer, but you'll have to adapt it a little bit.